# JTable position (x,y) location in JPanel

Tags: java

I have tried to position my JTable after list logo image but I did not succeed; it still stays in the end of the page.

```
setSize(900,600);
setLocation(400,80);

panel.setLayout (null);

//welcome.setBounds(70,50,150,60);
jimage.setBounds(300,20,203,91);
jaimage.setBounds(250,100,300,100);
backB.setBounds(830,5,50,50);
backB.addActionListener(this);

//panel.add(welcome);
panel.add(backB);
panel.add(jimage);
panel.add(jaimage);
panel.add(table);

panel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
panel.add(table, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
getContentPane().add(panel);

setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you provide an [mre], then I could copy the code into my IDE, run it, and test changes.  Since you've provided a code snippet, I cannot answer your question, other than to say, never use null layouts and absolute positioning.

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);` ← Don’t do that.  [Use layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/) instead.  They exist precisely to solve problems like this.

Comment: they don't allow me to copy all my code , i just want to place the table after the image not in the bottom

Comment: Create a panel with all your components (except) the table. Add that panel to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START. Then add the JScrollPane containing the table to the BorderLayout.CENTER.

Comment: thank you for your response , actually i solve my problem by using one panel and a null layout and setBounds to every element